# Create a CSV File with specific format from a String obtained after WS Invocation

Tags: r, bash, shell, unix, csv

The title is self explanatory. I am calling a web service which is returning a String like this :

`First Name="Kunal";Middle Name="";Last Name="Bhowmick";Address 1="HGB";Address 2="cvf";Address 3="tfg";City="DF";State="KL";Country="MN";Postal Code="0012";Telephone="(+98)6589745623"`

Now i have to write a shell script to create a csv file named `CSV_Output.csv` and the file must be formatted with the  String content.

The format must be something like this :

```
Field Name(in yellow color)      Value(in yellow color)

First Name                              Kunal
Middle Name
Last Name                               Bhowmick                            
Address 1                               HGB
Address 2                               cvf
Address 3                               tfg
City                                    DF
State                                   KL
Country                                 MN
Postal Code                             0012
Telephone                               (+98)6589745623
```

Now I can easily generate a CSV file using `redirection(>>)`, but how can i  create and format a CSV file like in the format show above ?

Sorry, to be blunt and i have no code to show as well, as i am not understanding what to use here.

Kindly provide some suggestions(sample code). Any help is greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an awk one-liner could convert the format:

```
awk -v RS="\\n|;" -v OFS="\t"  -F=  '{gsub(/"/,"");$1=$1}7' file
```

if you want the output to look better, you could pass the output to `column` and change the `OFS` like:

```
awk -v RS="\\n|;" -v OFS="#"  -F=  '{gsub(/"/,"");$1=$1}7' file|column -s"#" -t
```

the output is:

```
kent$  awk -v RS="\\n|;" -v OFS="#"  -F=  '{gsub(/"/,"");$1=$1}7' f|column -s"#" -t
First Name   Kunal
Middle Name  
Last Name    Bhowmick
Address 1    HGB
Address 2    cvf
Address 3    tfg
City         DF
State        KL
Country      MN
Postal Code  0012
Telephone    (+98)658974562
```

short explanation:

```
awk             #awk command
-v RS="\\n|;"   #set line separator is \n(newline) or ;(semi)
-v OFS="\t"     #set output field separator: <tab>
-F=             #set "=" as field separator
'{gsub(/"/,""); #remove all double quotes
$1=$1}          #$1=$1, to let awk reformat the line with given OFS
7'              #the non-zero number to print the whole line.
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely answer, i was looking for something with `awk` or `sed` especially. Can you kindly provide some explanation for the code, as i am not all that familiar with the workings of complex `awk` ? +1 for the `awk` way .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight appended the explanation at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved using `tr` and `column`:

```
$ cat input
First Name="Kunal";Middle Name="";Last Name="Bhowmick";Address 1="HGB";Address 2="cvf";Address 3="tfg";City="DF";State="KL";Country="MN";Postal Code="0012";Telephone="(+98)6589745623"

$ cat input | tr ";" "\n" | column -s= -t | tr -d \"
First Name   Kunal
Middle Name  
Last Name    Bhowmick
Address 1    HGB
Address 2    cvf
Address 3    tfg
City         DF
State        KL
Country      MN
Postal Code  0012
Telephone    (+98)6589745623
```

Split input on `;`; pipe the output to `column` specifying `=` as the delimiter, get rid of quotes!

`EDIT:` Didn't realize that you want a CSV.  In that event, use:

```
$ cat input | tr ";" "\n" | tr "=" "\t" | tr -d \"
```

which will result into a `TAB` delimited output.

Comment: Thanks , i will try this one out and let you know.